# how to check if tokenize string is in list of list

Tags: python, list

im looking to check if list is in list of my list, how can i dot it in python?

```
list=['hello','my','name','is','george']

my_list = ['hello','name']
```

```
#if any(list in sublist for sublist in my_list):
    if any(re.search(synonym,line) for synonym in my_list):
        return 'good'
    else:
        return 'nope'
```

but above code result is TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

Answer (score 0):

This will print good or nope for every item in my_list if list includes any of the elements in my_list.

```
list=['hello','my','name','is','george']

my_list = ['hello','name']

for item in my_list:
    if item in list:
        print('good')
    else:
        print('nope')
```